AMM - CLMM tick - optimal arbitrage trade amount
I'm trying to figure out, what kind of formula to use for getting an optimal trade amount between a CLMM (one tick only, so no price jumps) and AMM pool... For example, we see an arbitrage opportunity by a CLMM pool price being lower and an AMM pool where the price is higher.. How could we derive the optimal amount in or optimal tokenB amount to trade in first pool, so when we then swap the tokenB output into the AMM pool, both pool prices will "meet" after both swaps finish..
We already know the simple formula for 2 AMM markets (using constant product formula), mentioned here ... Since CLMM also use a similar constant product formula (within ticks), would there be a possibility of deriving the optimal trade amount between one tick and AMM mathematically, without binary searching, loops, etc....
